# Display one to many relation relations in the template django

Tags: django, templates, relationship

I have models in my model.py:
And I would like to display and edit these two models in a web page.
Someone can help me please.

1. parent: fdt_schedulejour

fdt_schedulejour

```
class fdt_schedulejour(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    commentaire = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fdt_schedulejour'

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.date)
```

2. child: fdt_activite.

fdt_schedulejour

```
class fdt_activite(models.Model):
    schedulejour = models.ForeignKey(fdt_schedulejour)
    debut = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    fin = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fdt_activite'

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.type)
```

Thank you

Comment: your question is too broad, did you take the tutorial?

Comment: Please share view and templates code then we can identify how you are trying to achieve the solution.

Comment: Can someone please help me please

Answer (score 0):

My view:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        messages.error(request,"Ajout impossible. Corrigez l'erreur et recommencez svp !!!")
        return redirect('/')
    else:
    add_appoint= fdt_schedulejour.objects.appointval(request.POST, request.session['id'])
    if add_appoint[0] == False:
        for each in add_appoint[1]:
            messages.error(request, each)
        return redirect('/appoint')
    if add_appoint[0] == True:
        messages.success(request, 'Ajout reussi avec succes')
        return redirect('/appoint')
```

templates:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Ajoutez vos heures </h2>
    {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li style="color:red">{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    <form action="/add" class="col s12" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

      <!-- PARENT: FDT_SCHEDULEJOUR -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="date" type="date" class="form-control" name="date">
          Date
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- CHILD: FDT_ACTIVITE -->
      <!--   NOT WORK -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="debut" type="time" step="any" class="form-control" name="debut">
          debut
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="fin" type="time" step="any" class="form-control" name="fin">
          fin
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="add" value="AJOUTER">
  </form>
</div>
```